# Loading nested Vue components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following nested components in part of my VueJS app. Each of the result in the search results uses Result.vue. Clicking a 'view more' button loads in the component MoreDetails.vue which in turn renders a Google Map.

```
SearchResults.vue
|
|__Result.vue
   |
   |__MoreDetails.vue
      |
      |__gmap.vue
```

When you click 'view more' I am getting the following error.

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: `<gmap>` - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

If I use gmap in the Result.vue file I don't get any issues.
Is there a limit on nesting?

Here is how gmap is being imported in MoreDetails.vue

```
<script>
import gmap from '../../widgets/gmap';

export default {
  components: { gmap },
  ...
}
</script>
```

This exact way of importing works fine in Result.vue

Comment: Do you import gmap.vue into MoreDetails.vue?

Comment: Yes, that's where the error is

Comment: you should provide the code for how you are importing the nested components. Otherwise it's hard to make a suggestsion

Comment: I've just updated to include the import

Comment: I don't see a problem so far in the posted code.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a limit to how deep the nesting can go?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: Show relevant templates parts of `Result` and `MoreDetails` please.